# text-overflow: ellipsis not working in a div containing a div in Chrome

Tags: html, css

I want to have all text be ending with '...' but it only works for the inner div:

```css
div {
  border: solid 2px blue;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div>Test test test test test test
  <div>asdasdasdasdasd</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JU8Up/

is there any Solution so that also the text contained in the outer div gets the '...' ?

edit: seems like its a chrome problem, but still the fix in the answer below works

Comment: I see ellipsis for both the outer as well as the inner text in FF (latest). Which browser are you testing with?

Comment: I'm seeing ellipsis on both in FF but only on the inner in Chrome.

Comment: right i was using chrome, edited the article accordingly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works by adding `float: left;` to the div CSS, but without any further context I can't comment on what side-effects that may have in your implementation.

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/JU8Up/1/).

Comment: Saw this property for the first time , just curious , how is it useful?

Comment: Which property, `float: left`? Or `text-overflow: ellipsis`?

Comment: It's a great way of ensuring that single-line text doesn't get cut off at its container edge, but rather displays a nice `...` to signify truncated content. See [this discussion thread](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/truncate-string-with-ellipsis/) for a couple of cool, vendor-specific alternatives.

Comment: ah it is also only needed to add the float property to the inner divs: http://jsfiddle.net/ggRnz/